# In this node.js image module, which should I use? (readStream or from path?)

Tags: image, memory, node.js, stream

What is a "Stream"? Which one below should I use for fastest? 
Is there a way to open it from Memory, like a buffer?

```
// can provide either a file path or a ReadableStream
// (from a local file or incoming network request)
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/my/img.jpg');
gm(readStream, 'img.jpg')
.write('/path/to/reformat.png', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('done');
});

// can also stream output to a ReadableStream
// (can be piped to a local file or remote server)
gm('/path/to/my/img.jpg')
.resize('200', '200')
.stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/my/resized.jpg');
  stdout.pipe(writeStream);
});

// pass a format or filename to stream() and
// gm will provide image data in that format
gm('/path/to/my/img.jpg')
.stream('png', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/my/reformated.png');
  stdout.pipe(writeStream);
});

// combine the two for true streaming image processing
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/my/img.jpg');
gm(readStream, 'img.jpg')
.resize('200', '200')
.stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/my/resized.jpg');
  stdout.pipe(writeStream);
});

// when working with input streams and any 'identify'
// operation (size, format, etc), you must pass "{bufferStream: true}" if
// you also need to convert (write() or stream()) the image afterwards
// NOTE: this temporarily buffers the image stream in Node memory
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/my/img.jpg');
gm(readStream, 'img.jpg')
.size({bufferStream: true}, function(err, size) {
  this.resize(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
  this.write('/path/to/resized.jpg', function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('done');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A stream reads data from a file one chunk at a time. It's useful for reading large files without having to store the entire contents in memory.

If you already have a stream opened and it hasn't started emitting data, pass the stream. Otherwise give it a path and it will have to open a new stream.